# Any way to make a change to every line of code with the same compiler warning?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

I recently became in charge of updating a large portion of code. One of the things I was asked to do was to reduce the number of compiler warnings, as since there were so many it was making it difficult to figure out what was important.

I have about 700 warnings that say: "The variable XXXXX is assigned but its value is never used", and sure, I could go and fix every line by hand, but this isn't the only type of warning I have.

What I was wondering is if there was a tool (in Visual Studio or otherwise) I could use to detect a specific warning type, and make an edit to every line of code that has that warning.

I googled around a little, but couldn't find anyone with a similar problem. Maybe someone could point me in the right direction?

Comment: Do you have ReSharper or some other Addon´s like this installed? If not you can disable a single error with `#pragma warning( disable : yourWarning)`

Comment: I don't know 100% as I am not particularly familiar with Visual Studio and just inherited this workspace, but I don't believe so. Also I'd rather not just disable the warning, but actually address the issue.

Comment: Another question: do you want to remove the variables or just want to ignore the warning?

Comment: I'd like to comment out all of the variables, in case someone wants to use them in the future.

Comment: @A.Sooga that's what source control is for. Unless you inspect every single line to write something meaningful, any comment you enter will be noise. Instead of littering the code with 100s of comments, remove the unneeded variables and add an appropriate comment in the commit message

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, there is a way. You need Visual Studio 2015 or 2017 for that.

First, open a file with a particular warning you're interested in.

Go to the line of code that produces that warning and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd>.

You will see a Code Fix window:[image: Code Fix window]

Click on the *Fix all occurrences in **Solution*** link.

You'll get a window that lets you preview the changes.

Finally, click the **Apply** button.

Comment: Cool! Thank you.

Comment: It won't let me accept this answer for another minute, though

Answer (score 1):

`#pragma warning` can enable or disable certain warnings.

[#pragma warning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/preprocessor-pragma-warning)

```
#pragma warning disable CS0219 // Variable is assigned but its value is never used
            //here goes the code with the variables which are never used....
#pragma warning restore CS0219 // Variable is assigned but its value is never used
```

With the `#pragma warning` you can keep you variables for future purpose.